# Horizontal spacing of second line in a custom list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation, enumitem

I am trying to construct my own custom list environment, and it would be a great help to solve the problem below.

I would like a list environment that took a mandatory argument which gave the text to be displayed as the label, so far I have this

```
\newenvironment{mylist}[1]
    {
    \begin{itemize}[label=#1]
    }{
    \end{itemize}
    }
```

This works so far, but when the text in a single list item overflows into the next line it looks like this

```
Example: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
         aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

however I would like it to look like this

```
Example: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

with the text on the second and subsequent lines at a definable distance from the left margin of the page (or from the left edge of the current environment, whatever that may be).

I have tried using the `enumitem` package, with the `itemindent` option, but all that seems to do is shift the second line left relative to its indented position. What I would like to do is shift the second line right from a non indented position.

Edit: a mwe

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

%Used in my LaTeX document that I'm preparing, just in case there is some conflict between this and any proposed solution
\setlist{topsep=0mm,partopsep=0mm,parsep=0mm,itemsep=0.1mm,leftmargin=*}

\newenvironment{mylist}[1]
{
\begin{itemize}[label=#1]
}{
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}{Example:}
    \item   Some text just to illustrate what happens when there is too much text and it overflows onto the next line.
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I've now added a MWE :)

Comment: @Eddy: Please post clear questions :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry, I'll try to post less minimal working examples in future so it's clear what the problem is. I do appreciate the help though :)

Comment: @Eddy: Actually, my example did what you requested, indenting the first and the second level. You're misusing the features of `enumitem` by defining an extra `mylist` environment whereas this could be done with `\newlist` more easily.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The mylist environment will contain far more (and have a different name) than was presented in my MWE, I was just trying to keep everything consistent between the full version and the version presented here. In addition "the text on the second and subsequent lines at a definable distance from the left margin of the page" did not seem to work with your solution (correct me if I'm wrong) since when the word "Example:" was replaced with any other word, the distance changed. I should have included two lists, with different words, which would have made my MWE clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following MWE will help you solve the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Used in my LaTeX document that I'm preparing, just in case there is some conflict between this and any proposed solution

\setlist[itemize]{wide,topsep=0mm,partopsep=0mm,parsep=0mm,itemsep=0.1mm,labelindent=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}

\newenvironment{mylist}[1]
{
\begin{itemize}[label=#1]
}{
\end{itemize}
}



\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mylist}{Example:}
    \item   Some text just to illustrate what happens when there is too much text and it overflows onto the next line.
    \item   Some text just to illustrate what happens when there is too much text and it overflows onto the next line.
\end{mylist}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I have now change `\setlist` from:

```
\setlist{topsep=0mm,partopsep=0mm,parsep=0mm,itemsep=0.1mm,leftmargin=*}
```

to

```
\setlist[itemize]{wide,topsep=0mm,partopsep=0mm,parsep=0mm,itemsep=0.1mm,labelindent=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}
```

You can adjust `leftmargin=<dimension>` to set the left margin from second line onwards.

Comment: So leftmargin=* aligns the content with the label, but leftmargin=<dimension> sets the distance between the left margin and the content?

Comment: @Eddy: Yes. It is right.

Comment: Ok, great! glad it was me being dumb and not that this was something really hard. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Jagath AR: `wide, labelindent=0pt` can be shortened to `wide=0pt`.